# Chrome DevTools error: "Failed to save to temp variable."

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am using [Node Monkey](https://github.com/jwarkentin/node-monkey) to debug my NodeJS app.

It happens frequently that when I click "Store as Global Variable" in my Chrome Console it says "Failed to save to temp variable."

[image]

```
console.log({why:'dont', you:'work?'})
```

It happens also in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8uqvak0o/)

1) Am I doing something wrong?

2) Why this happens?

Chrome: 50.0.2661.102 (64-bit)
OSX El Capitan 10.11.4

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I can see two reasons why Store As Global Variable wouldn't work:

**1. Wrong Console Context Selected**

This is arguably a Chrome bug, but you can only store an object as a global if the console is set to the same context as the code that logged the object.

In practice this means you might need to select the correct IFrame or web worker.

For example, on jsFiddle:

[image]

In the normal jsFiddle editor page context I'm getting an error. But it works if I change the context to the contents of the fiddle itself:

[image]

**2. Garbage Collection**

In order for Chrome to give you a reference to the object the object still has to be in memory. If that isn't the case it can only throw an error.

However, I'm pretty sure that being shown in the console forces V8 to keep a reference to the value.

Comment: Thank you! It helps me (In my case I was need to select an `iframe`)

Comment: brilliant, it was number 2 for me using react native debugger

Comment: Why does it have to switch context? Is it a different process?

Comment: @Tope did you find a way around this? Going through the same thing with React-Native debugger

Comment: @wheresmyspaceship i dont recall if it was about making sure i had that component mounted or not. but perhaps. pardon me.

Comment: @Tope Same. So how DO I save variable like this in R native?

Comment: worked like a charm in codesandbox as well

Answer (score 8):

You need to create the object in the Console itself, as the reference to the object needs to be maintained by Chrome. Just put the following into the console instead:

```
{why:'dont', you:'work?'}
```

[image: Console]

If you check out [this revision](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?revision=169649&view=revision) where the feature was added, it says:

> Adding ability to access objects from printed ObjectPropertySections
>   (console, scopes pane and etc.).

The problem, based on my understanding, is that `console.log` is outputting a string representation of the object, and just using object formatters to display it nicely. The object doesn't exist anymore. When you create an object through the console itself, Chrome is storing the object itself in memory. If you have paused on a breakpoint and have locally scoped variables, these can also be stored globally because they are also in memory.

One thing you could do in your code, if you haven't got circular references is:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify({why:'dont', you:'work?'}));
> {"why":"dont","you":"work?"}
```

In the Console, copy the output and paste it into a `JSON.parse` call:

```
JSON.parse('{"why":"dont","you":"work?"}');
> Object {why: "dont", you: "work?"}
```

The variable exists now in memory so you can store it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It works, but I usually "Store as Global Variable" also an object printed using a console.log, for example, I can save the Object printed by this HTML page:
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log({why:'dont', you:'work?'})
</script>

The problem is that sometimes this "Store as Global Variable" doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Comment: @DevidFarinelli I updated my answer to add some more details and a possible workaround for you.

Comment: Thanks @Gideon again for your help, that's interesting. Today "Store as Global Variable" works for my nodejs app using console.log({why:'dont', you:'work?'}) but doesn't work for the jsfiddle.
I'm confused.

Comment: @DevidFarinelli The reason it doesn't work on jsFiddle is probably because of the context that's selected in the console being set to the fiddle editor, not the fiddle result which is logging the object.

Comment: @MattZeunert Thanks for answering the JSFiddle comment. Missed that. Makes sense :)

Comment: I tried to console.log() in codepen and got the same issue on

Answer (score 2):

press `Ctrl+Shift+C` and select any element inside the frame that prints the object, then try again.

This will fix the problem.

Comment: I don't know why this works..... but it does. ty