# Failed to save to temp variable in chrome developer tool

Tags: global-variables, google-chrome-devtools

In chrome developer tool, we can save object values to a variable using "store as global variable". But I have been given an error as follows. 
"Failed to save to temp variable."

[image: chrome developer tool]

Comment: In this case, what are you trying to store as a global variable? The array of objects or the array of strings?

Comment: Yes, I am using The array of objects

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562683/chrome-devtools-error-failed-to-save-to-temp-variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is your object `console.log`'d from an `iframe`? That would make sense since the `iframe` has its own scope.

Try creating the same object in the root html scope (not in an `iframe`) and try the "store as a global variable" button.